# WIX Installer not Uninstalling Windows Service and application files. Install process appears to complete without errors

Tags: visual-studio, service, wix

My WIX Installer for some reason has stopped working, basically the windows service installs correctly and the associated folder structure is generated as expected. However when I elect to uninstall the service, the service does not get removed, and the application folder structure remains in place, when it should be removed.  Can anybody offer some fresh insight into this issue please, as it is driving me insane, already spent an entire afternoon on this, frustration levels are off the scale... :-)

Detailed below is the 'product.wxs' file for the installer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?define SourceDir = "D:\users\userid\Documents\_VSSWorkArea\PSALERTS 2014\Bin\Debug" ?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"  xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">
<Product Id="*" Name="PSALERTS Schedule Server" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="Iberdrola, S.A." UpgradeCode="4bf02e34-a9b6-41a3-ba2a-238e78f77bca">
<Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />
<Binary Id="ADXDPCADLL" SourceFile="Resources\Binary\adxdpca.dll" />
<Binary Id="InstallUtilConfig" SourceFile="Resources\Binary\InstallUtilConfig" />
<MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
<MediaTemplate EmbedCab="yes" />
<Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="ScheduleServerSetup" Level="1">
  <ComponentRef Id="comp_dir_B28CB493_75A9_447F_A3A8_F2321E0F7C70" />
  <ComponentRef Id="comp_dir_4454F06F_75E4_41A5_A28A_CF2F9F204C7F" />
  <ComponentRef Id="comp_dir_81FADF40_F042_4236_A70C_23AA0E8B3AF5" />
  <ComponentRef Id="comp_dir_Output" />
  <ComponentRef Id="cmpAED6DCE8E0AB00E3C379FE91A79198FB" />
  <ComponentRef Id="cmp958A250AB9BD3F3610353B9CAE6D1DAD" />
  <ComponentRef Id="cmp713FB5985AD306661C14B5CAF8915358" />
  <ComponentRef Id="cmp5C017CCC79271ABC574549EC7C2EE35D" />
  <ComponentRef Id="cmp162886C5A673D08E34719E4E5C4DD2F1" />
  <ComponentRef Id="cmp40C4B73A67F3096BBCCBE01D20DE3141" />
  <ComponentRef Id="cmp3C7621AC7C4EA302468AB62924FB0C50" />
  <ComponentRef Id="cmp6E65FBFED192168BFDB3E2BD02467058" />
  <ComponentRef Id="cmp51539E0716A9502013C2F4F1C4A40422" />
  <ComponentRef Id="cmp8812D6250E9087B0D6CDF0CFB39B1879" />
  <ComponentRef Id="cmpA8746837808C42CF1822693C1323D357" />
  <ComponentRef Id="cmp38EAF68AD299F7500722CE857644D5AB" />
  <ComponentRef Id="cmp1BF6C202F78E44E848E6EC01C9C89319" />
  <ComponentRef Id="cmp2F0DA692FCFCFC0C579C37EA84DAC75A" />
  <ComponentRef Id="cmp612693FF751FC9F39309B69CA766CBFD" />
  <ComponentRef Id="cmp220CC346603D718312CF9B1EDA09FA7A" />
  <ComponentRef Id="cmp90F1671FA722D400EA4DB6A5C413A4AE" />
</Feature>

<UI>
  <Error Id="1001"><![CDATA[Error [1]. [2]]]></Error>
</UI>

</Product>
<Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
        <Directory Id="dir_4454F06F_75E4_41A5_A28A_CF2F9F204C7F" Name="SP Energy Networks">
          <Component Id="comp_dir_4454F06F_75E4_41A5_A28A_CF2F9F204C7F" Guid="57F80F55-52CB-455E-BF23-E7D34491D559" KeyPath="yes" Transitive="yes" />
          <Directory Id="dir_B28CB493_75A9_447F_A3A8_F2321E0F7C70" Name="PSALERTS">
            <Component Id="comp_dir_B28CB493_75A9_447F_A3A8_F2321E0F7C70" Guid="1C49F332-B7AE-4E72-BE26-FC8794A97A4A" KeyPath="yes" Transitive="yes" />
            <Directory Id="dir_81FADF40_F042_4236_A70C_23AA0E8B3AF5" Name="Schedule Server">
              <Component Id="comp_dir_81FADF40_F042_4236_A70C_23AA0E8B3AF5" Guid="D7C033D9-ACBB-4404-8A5C-226A2A321D8A" KeyPath="yes">
                <CreateFolder Directory="dir_81FADF40_F042_4236_A70C_23AA0E8B3AF5" />
                <RemoveFile Id="PurgeScheduleServer" Name="*.*" On="uninstall" />                  
            <RemoveFolder Id="id_4CB8303D_8215_4F47_A668_D2A31B46B18A"On="uninstall" Directory="dir_81FADF40_F042_4236_A70C_23AA0E8B3AF5" />
              </Component>
                <Directory Id="dir_Output" Name="Output">              
              <Component Id="comp_dir_Output" Guid="{A39E21F4-C163-442E-B98D-8F7453A6A16D}" KeyPath="yes">
                <CreateFolder Directory="dir_Output" />
                <RemoveFile Id="PurgeOutput" Name="*.*" On="uninstall" />                    
                <RemoveFolder Id="dir_OutputRemove" On="uninstall" Directory="dir_Output" />
              </Component>
            </Directory>    
              <Component Id="cmpAED6DCE8E0AB00E3C379FE91A79198FB" Guid="{3381B7AB-0632-452A-A978-CA9B80AF01B9}">
            <File Id="fil6EBAA968155E705343D8749D328C4E07" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.SourceDir)\scheduleserver.exe" />
                <ServiceInstall Id="cmpAED6DCE8E0AB00E3C379FE91A79198FB" Type="ownProcess" Name="PSALERTS Schedule Server" DisplayName="PSALERTS Schedule Server"
                            Description="PSALERTS Schedule Server" Start="demand" Account="LocalSystem" ErrorControl="normal">
                            <util:PermissionEx  User="Everyone" ServicePauseContinue="yes" ServiceQueryStatus="yes"
                                    ServiceStart="yes" ServiceStop="yes" ServiceUserDefinedControl="yes" />                      
                </ServiceInstall>
                <ServiceControl Id="cmpAED6DCE8E0AB00E3C379FE91A79198FB" Start="install" Stop="both" Remove="both" Name="PSALERTS Schedule Server" Wait="no" />                                
            <RemoveRegistryKey Id="RemoveScheduleServerRegKey" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\SP Energy Networks\PSALERTS\Schedule Server" Action="removeOnUninstall" />
          </Component> 
                <Component Id="cmp958A250AB9BD3F3610353B9CAE6D1DAD" Guid="{97B9F8B0-A2AC-467B-8212-F423F538FFC3}">
                <File Id="filC41098B854A631CF6DBA2BFEDF068D5A" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.SourceDir)\ScheduleServer.pdb" />
            </Component>  


              <Component Id="cmp713FB5985AD306661C14B5CAF8915358" Guid="{B405CBBC-99F4-47AF-8032-55898E99A10A}">
            <File Id="filD5757A3CB827456E0013B9566B2FC084" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.SourceDir)\BusinessLogic.dll"/>
          </Component>
          <Component Id="cmp5C017CCC79271ABC574549EC7C2EE35D" Guid="{F6BF6F7E-6765-4BB9-9FC7-CDD5965BFDB8}">
            <File Id="fil343568DF8E4707FF503B613E70A0A355" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.SourceDir)\BusinessLogic.pdb" />
          </Component>
          <Component Id="cmp162886C5A673D08E34719E4E5C4DD2F1" Guid="{DB83D343-7353-42E8-90AD-AD5B76EE5363}">
            <File Id="filA9EEE0FEE529CC3EFBF88BD055CFE306" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.SourceDir)\BusinessObject.dll" />
          </Component>
          <Component Id="cmp40C4B73A67F3096BBCCBE01D20DE3141" Guid="{8AB16A3F-D341-4023-A7DC-4B8C2CAFC1AD}">
            <File Id="filD42108F965212B0DDBAA35D4C61CD465" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.SourceDir)\BusinessObject.pdb" />
          </Component>
          <Component Id="cmp3C7621AC7C4EA302468AB62924FB0C50" Guid="{A24D3C5F-1358-4B04-9791-EF4A20E292F7}">
            <File Id="filE524B37660FBFCDBE4422296EB75945D" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.SourceDir)\Common.dll" />
          </Component>
          <Component Id="cmp6E65FBFED192168BFDB3E2BD02467058" Guid="{6D07F55E-38D7-4E38-A268-B544638F3101}">
            <File Id="fil2386387A70A2D5715D26A1C0AECA8F72" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.SourceDir)\Common.pdb" />
          </Component>
          <Component Id="cmp51539E0716A9502013C2F4F1C4A40422" Guid="{324D79C7-CBD6-4A31-BA5C-2D80543FD3E0}">
            <File Id="fil3A5E266322C8027A40AB6251ABB418E3" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.SourceDir)\DataAccess.dll" />
          </Component>
          <Component Id="cmp8812D6250E9087B0D6CDF0CFB39B1879" Guid="{80067CE4-1E34-4954-80D7-BAA3A8CE976C}">
            <File Id="filA51C5C2737848ABA913D6DF4B024CBE5" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.SourceDir)\DataAccess.pdb" />
          </Component>
          <Component Id="cmpA8746837808C42CF1822693C1323D357" Guid="{08833C08-5CA4-430B-A053-330A305C44A3}">
            <File Id="fil926C30E09F8A050F884226CA62B42B13" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.SourceDir)\DPAPIHelper.dll" />
          </Component>
          <Component Id="cmp38EAF68AD299F7500722CE857644D5AB" Guid="{D74E5847-1682-4A9C-8457-BE8CDECF0632}">
            <File Id="filD685EADB0F07BADC12833E53F643B8B7" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.SourceDir)\DPAPIHelper.pdb" />
          </Component>
          <Component Id="cmp1BF6C202F78E44E848E6EC01C9C89319" Guid="{ABCAD478-0F86-40FB-8FA3-783316387D94}">
            <File Id="fil44AA274730F17C919C76111C248BB071" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.SourceDir)\Logger.dll" />
          </Component>
          <Component Id="cmp2F0DA692FCFCFC0C579C37EA84DAC75A" Guid="{7F87A413-1018-4C23-83E8-AED9EF0347D8}">
            <File Id="filEFB6EF0671B140F3F56CFE74B0C804D9" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.SourceDir)\Logger.pdb" />
          </Component>
          <Component Id="cmp612693FF751FC9F39309B69CA766CBFD" Guid="{B542B099-702E-41B5-80A5-27BE819119A5}">
            <File Id="fil64FE4F5C2200B3A7081D6DD71368CE3F" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.SourceDir)\ScheduleServer.ico" />
          </Component>
          <Component Id="cmp220CC346603D718312CF9B1EDA09FA7A" Guid="{4D125F45-7C14-4827-993C-78CFA537A3DF}">
            <File Id="fil89291CBB1B93A1566242B04B9B298A5B" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.SourceDir)\ScheduleServer.ini" />
          </Component>
          <Component Id="cmp90F1671FA722D400EA4DB6A5C413A4AE" Guid="{8B506F64-03EF-4923-9A81-FFBE690A0286}">
            <File Id="fil2C57307B216B5A4D41323E432197DDEF" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.SourceDir)\PSALERTS.xltm" />
          </Component>
            </Directory>
          </Directory>
        </Directory>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
  </Fragment>
  <Fragment>
  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Comment: You should try wait="yes" in your ServiceControl. otherwise the MSI just tells the service to stop and carries on whether it has actually stopped or not. It could still be running when the uninstall finishes, so it won't remove the files.  Do the files disappear after a reboot?

Comment: I should also have said that the installation is removed from 'Programs & Features' as if the installtion has in fact completed properly.

Comment: Thanks for your response Phil, changing to wait="yes" did not make any difference.  And thinking on this, I implement another WIX installer, also for a windows service which does not suffer from this problem, and this one has wait="no".  Similarly re-booting the machine subsequent to an uninstall has no effect on the files.

Comment: It looks like you'll need to debug what your service does when it gets the shut down message. It might stop being a service, but the process keeps running; or there might be some code somewhere with a handle open to the service.  Does the service entry get removed from the services list? If yes, then the service has stopped being a service but the process itself still runs and so can't be removed until after a reboot.